# ExpressJS set the Depth of JSON Parsing

Tags: json, express, body-parser

I want to set the depth of JSON parsing in Express middleware `express.json()`.

For example, if I would set the option to parse the `depth=1`, then

```
'{ "email": { "$ne": "user@example.com" } }'
```

will be parsed to

```
{ email: "[object Object]" }
```

-- or --

When I set `depth=2`, then

```
'{ "email": { "$ne": "user@example.com" } }'
```

will be parsed to

```
{ email: { '$ne': 'user@example.com' } }
```

And so on,

In this case, there will be no issue of default depth, as the developer will be aware of how many nesting they will allow while development.

PS: It will prevent the application from being vulnerable to NoSQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write you own [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html):

```js
const get_depth = (obj) => {
    let depth = 0
    for(const key in obj) {
        if( obj[key] instanceof Object ) {
          depth = Math.max(get_depth(obj[key]), depth)
        }
    }
    return depth+1
}
const depth_limit = 2
const limit_depth = function(req, res, next) {
    if( get_depth(req.body) > depth_limit ) throw new Error("Possible NoSQL Injection")
    next()
}

app.use(limit_depth)
```

Or, if you prefer `"[object Object]"`:

```js
let limit_depth = (obj, current_depth, limit) => {
    for(const key in obj) {
        if( obj[key] instanceof Object ) {
          if( current_depth+1 === limit ) {
            obj[key] = "[object Object]" // or something similar
          }
          else limit_depth(obj[key], current_depth+1, limit)
        }
    }
}
app.use(function(req, res, next) { limit_depth(req.body, 0, depth_limit); next() })
```

Comment: Can I use it to create my own middleware?

Comment: `limit_depth` as it is is a complete middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I write down the query, Maximum 6-8 depth goes. when use lookup inside the lookup.

```
  const [result] = await Collection.aggregate([
    { $match:statusObj },
     {
         $project:{
             _id:1,
             name:1
             }
     },
     {
      $lookup:{
           from:"articles",
            let: { "cat_id":"$_id"},
            pipeline:[
             {
                $match:{
                     $expr:{
                  $and: [
                         { $eq: ["$category_id", "$$cat_id"] }, 
                         { $eq: ["$isDeleted", false] },
                         { $eq: ["$type", type] }
                         ]
                     }

                    } 
                 },
                  {
      $lookup:{
           from:"view_articles",
            let: { "article_id":"$_id"},
            pipeline:[
             {
                $match:{
                     $expr:{
                  $and: [
                         { $eq: ["$article_id", "$$article_id"] }, 
                         { $eq: ["$isDeleted", false] }
                         ]
                     }

                    } 
                 }
                 ],
                 as:"viewCount"
          }    
    },
    {
      $addFields:{
          noOfViewCount : { $size:"$viewCount"}
          }   
      }          ],
                 as:"articleCategoryData"
          }    
    },
     {
      $addFields: {
      postCount: {$size:"$articleCategoryData"   },
      tempsArray: { $map:
        {
           input: "$articleCategoryData",
           as: "tempData",
           in: { $add: "$$tempData.noOfViewCount" }
        }
     },
                 },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          viewCount:{ $sum:"$tempsArray" }
              },
        },
        {
          $project:{
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            postCount: 1,
            viewCount: 1
              }
      },
      {
        $facet: {
          count: [
            {
              $count: "total"
            }
          ],
          result: [{ $match: {} }, { $skip: skipRecord }, { $limit: limit }]
        }
      }
]);
```

you can set depth to 10. If you feel JSON is coming wrong then increase it :)

Comment: This is part of MongoDB. The ques is regarding express js. Or in more depth body parser library by express. Read the ques once again.

Comment: Thanks got it and besides it help me in payload the limit. only specific depth of JSON receive in payload.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone who doesn't want to change the value of `req.body`, can use this function from [here](https://github.com/tbhaxor/mongo-secure/blob/main/index.ts#L26)

```
function serializer(payload: any, cdepth: number, options: Options): void {
  const main: any = {}
  const maxDepth = typeof options.maxNestingLevel == 'number' ? (options.maxNestingLevel == 0 ? 1 : options.maxNestingLevel) : 1

  for (const key in payload) {
    // check for object
    if (payload[key] instanceof Object) {
      // check if depth is limited, replace if needed
      if (cdepth === maxDepth) {
        main[key] = options.replaceWith
      } else {
        // serialize the nested
        main[key] = serializer(payload[key], cdepth + 1, options)
      }
    } else {
      // add to main object if not to be checked
      main[key] = payload[key]
    }
  }
  return main
}
```